# Book where people live on a meteor that was alive

Tags: story-identification

The cover was dark green and had a pink jelly fish blob looking thing on it. The book was about a group of people who had to live and train on the meteor and there was even a giant room in the meteor that was designed to be like living on earth, and then conflict arose where people split into 2 groups and they were burning each others crops and killing each other and stealing from each other. there was also a part where they discovered how to make alcohol. Ive been looking for this book for 3 years now and would kill to find it again.

Comment: Sounds something like 'Heart of the Comet' by Brin & Benford, but I'm not sure about some of the details.

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents. I agree. You should post this as the answer. The wiki description can be found here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_the_Comet